# No primary detected for set [Mongo shell]

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongo-shell

My current version of MongoDb is 3.2.7
I am trying to connect to my db with this

```
"mongo mongodb://meanbeta-shard-00-00-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-01-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-02-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017/test?replicaSet=MEANbeta-shard-0" --authenticationDatabase admin --ssl --username xxxx --password xxxxx
```

Yesterday I was able to connect through mongo shell, but today it is giving me error but I am still able to connect using Compass App:

```
 
  2017-10-20T20:34:04.682+0530 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for MEANbeta-shard-0/meanbeta-shard-00-00-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-01-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-02-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017
2017-10-20T20:34:04.682+0530 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] starting
2017-10-20T20:34:07.708+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set MEANbeta-shard-0
2017-10-20T20:34:11.095+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set MEANbeta-shard-0
2017-10-20T20:34:14.516+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set MEANbeta-shard-0
2017-10-20T20:34:16.637+0530 W NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitorWatcher] No primary detected for set MEANbeta-shard-0
2017-10-20T20:34:20.056+0530 W NETWORK  [thread1] No primary detected for set MEANbeta-shard-0
2017-10-20T20:34:20.056+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: connect failed to replica set MEANbeta-shard-0/meanbeta-shard-00-00-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-01-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017,meanbeta-shard-00-02-sshqm.mongodb.net:27017 :
```

I am new to MongoDB and to its Replica Set concept, please help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: All of a  sudden it worked after updating Mongo Shell

Answer (score 4):

Don't install mongo shell from apt-get , since it installs an older version. You need **MongoDB shell version v3.4.10** or above for it to work .

I also had the same problem before I installed the newer version from the link shown in the **connect to cluster from shell dialog on the mongo website**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it worked for me. Don't user apt commandline to install.

Comment: 3.4.10 didn't work for me, but 3.6.21 did

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Natesh,

```
echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
echo 'http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
apk update && \
apk add mongodb=3.6.7-r0 && \
mongo --version
```

worked for me.